# NSCFArray length Error iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsarray, nsdata

I tried to save am NSArray to an Existing MutableArray that contained elements or objects.

I successfully added the array to the mutablemarray and logged the array and also logged the array count for it. Everything seemed to be okay until I wanted to add the 5 saved values to my `UITableView`.

My App crashes with a weird exception. I have tried absolutely everything but nothing seems to work.

I have no idea of where to continue debugging.

Saved Prefs in beginning of app.

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *defineXMLData in getSpecialsAuth) {

NSArray * imageUrl = [defineXMLData objectForKey:@"imageUrl"];
[specialsimageUrlArray addObject: imageUrl];
[specialsimageUrlArray addObject: test];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:specialsimageUrlArray forKey:@"specialsImageUrlArray"];

}
```

SpecialsViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.specialsArray = [prefs arrayForKey:@"specialsImageUrlArray"];
NSMutableArray *specialsimageUrlArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
test = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells3.jpg", nil];           
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 NSData *imageData= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.specialsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];    
UIImageView *imageViewForCell = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,3,30,30)];
imageViewForCell.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
[imv addSubview:imageViewForCell];

 }
```

NSLog

```
 SpecialsArray (
"http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells1.jpg",
"http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells1.jpg",
"http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells3.jpg",
"http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells2.jpg",
    (
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells3.jpg"
)
)

Specials Count (
 5
 )
```

Error Log

```
  -[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15dde4f0
CRASH: -[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15dde4f0
 Stack Trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2f3bbe9b <redacted> + 154
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x397186c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2f3bf7b7 <redacted> + 202
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2f3be0af <redacted> + 706
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2f30cdc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5   CoreFoundation                      0x2f311983 _CFURLInitWithURLString + 38
6   Foundation                          0x2fcf49a1 <redacted> + 212
7   Foundation                          0x2fcf48b3 <redacted> + 50
8   Bells                               0x0009b157 -[SpecialsDetailViewController downloadSpecialImage] + 110
9   Foundation                          0x2fd9633f __NSFireDelayedPerform + 414
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2f386e7f <redacted> + 14
11  CoreFoundation                      0x2f386a9b <redacted> + 794
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2f384e23 <redacted> + 1218
13  CoreFoundation                      0x2f2ef471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2f2ef253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
15  GraphicsServices                    0x340292eb GSEventRunModal + 138
16  UIKit                               0x31ba4845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
17  Bells                               0x00142f61 main + 116
18  libdyld.dylib                       0x39c11ab7 <redacted> + 2
)
```

Comment: can you add this method? [SpecialsDetailViewController downloadSpecialImage]

Comment: What is the type of `specialsimageUrlArray`?

Comment: I suspect that the message (`length`) was originally intended to be sent to a string (seems like sort of URL parsing stuff to me), but for some reason (memory corruption?) it has been sent to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This log:

```
 SpecialsArray (
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells1.jpg",
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells1.jpg",
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells3.jpg",
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells2.jpg",
    (
        "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells3.jpg"
    )
)
```

Shows that your specials array contains 4 string and 1 array. So when you try to use each item as a string you have a problem.

The cause is:

```
[specialsimageUrlArray addObject: test];
```

Because `test` is an array so you should be using `addObjectsFromArray:` to add its contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
SpecialsArray (
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells1.jpg",
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells1.jpg",
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells3.jpg",
    "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells2.jpg",
    (
        "http://dev.wigroup.co/bells/cvs_images/bells3.jpg"
    )
)
```

When you try to get NSData from first 4 URLs then it is working but the 5th element is an `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`).

So `NSData *imageData= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.specialsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];` line encounters problem while doing `[NSURL URLWithString:[self.specialsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]` i.e converting your array object to `NSURL` from `NSString`. **But it is an ARRAY.** That's the reason.

You should check for the type of object by using `isKindOfClass`

**A small example**

```
if([[self.specialsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])

{
  // It's NSString
}
else if([[self.specialsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] || [[self.specialsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
{
   // It's an array
}
```